# How can I hide the button var from Figures in Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave

I am trying to hide the button toolbox that appears in Octave figures (the one with Rotate, Zoom In, Zoom Out, Pan, Insert Text, Grid, Autoscale buttons).

I have seen that there is a property that, if I understood it correctly, it could be used to do this:

https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.0/Uibuttongroup-Properties.html#Uibuttongroup-Properties

However, I do not know how to set property "visible" to "off".
I have tried:

```
fig1 = figure(1)
plot(a(:,6))
set(get(fig1,"uibuttongroup"), "visible", "off")
```

Without success.

How can I set that property to "off"?

Note: I include also the tag "matlab" in case someone wants to share the same operations to see if that works too in Octave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same solution as in Matlab works in Octave:

```
set(fig1, 'toolbar', 'none')
```

As side notes, you can also remove the menu options:

```
set(fig1, 'menubar', 'none')
```

or change the window title:

```
set(fig1, 'numbertitle', 'off', 'name', 'example title')
```